# How to upload photos in Wordpress localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, image-uploading

I'm using Wordpress on localhost, but I can't upload photos. They seem broken and won't show, although they are created in wp-content/uploads/2014/01 folder. This folder has 755 mode, too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: right click on the photo and "inspect element" in chrome report the url that is being used to display the image

Comment: src="localhost/wp-uploads/2014/12/boat-150x150.jpg" so
I went to Dashboard/Settings/media and set url to "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads" since by default my uploaded photos went there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`755` give `read` and `execute`  permissions to `group` and `others` but **not** `write` permissions

I also find that sometimes its not enough for files/folders to have write permissions with wordpress you sometimes need to give your server `ownership` of the directory - if its going to regularly be reading and writing to it.
e.g. if apache is server on debian or debian derivative try:

```
sudo chown -R www-data wp-content/uploads/2014
```

(replace www-data with whatever user your server runs as)